# How to send events from thread to another

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a thread that receives data from a sensor and I it raises
events upon receiving each data item. This rate can be quite fast.
I'm also using WPF to display the data.

On the one hand the data is coming too fast for the UI thread and 
it is foolish to try and update the UI at that rate.

On the other hand I'm working on a class that will need all that data
to do its work. Lets call that the motion-processor (MP).

Currently the MP is instantiated off the main UI thread so I will have to move
it into its own thread. And I'm not sure how to attach a listener
from one thread to another. That's the first question.

Ideally I'd want the MP thread to receive all the updates from the sensor
thread and the MP thread would fire events to the UI thread. Or the MP thread
would have a property bound to a UI element and update the property at a 
much slower and timed rate.

I could just manually poll through time and update the property that way... but I've used the Threading Timer before and it seems like a cleaner approach. But then that's throwing one more thread into the mix and probably making this more complicated then it needs to be.

I know the sensor-thread is actually executing the handlers and I'd like
to reduce the work it is doing so that it is less likely to miss data
from the sensor.

So I guess this is a design question on how others would approach this
with the following key points:

1. the sensor thread needs to push the data quickly and get back to 
   listening for more data
2. the MP thread needs to receive that
       data, do a bunch of stuff including
                updating the UI at a reasonable speed.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: The question as asked is way too broad. There are lots of ways to solve this. That said, IMHO one of the simplest is to accumulate the updates, and marshal periodically (i.e. when enough have accumulated or enough time has passed) them over to the UI thread in the usual way (i.e. using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`). The logic to accumulate can reside in either the MP object or (IMHO preferably) the UI code (i.e. since it's the UI code that requires the accumulation behavior, put the logic there instead of complicating the MP implementation for that one scenario).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to sum things up, you want to run a monitor task in the background which feeds all data to your "MP" class and periodically update your UI?

The first point I would make is regarding your statement:
"Currently the MP is instantiated off the main UI thread so I will have to move it into its own thread. And I'm not sure how to attach a listener from one thread to another. That's the first question."

The fact you have instantiated the MP class from your UI thread has no relevance to the thread it will run on. Every method and property in your MP class could be set to run on independent threads regardless what thread the class that instantiated it is running on.

The problem you need to work out is a sensible relationship between the sensor, the MP and the UI.

Depending how you are populating the data for the UI, the actual method to do this will vary greatly (Are we updating the UI from code-behind, dependency properties or view models?), but the basic flow should go something like this:

1. Sensor sends all data to MP class.
2. MP class processes data, and at a set interval (use either something from System.Timers or an async method with a Task.Delay to perform the timing) raise your "UI Needs Update" method.

As said the actual "UI Needs Update" method will vary depending how your UI is bound to your data.

Hope that helps.